# reference the user to the created note nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

alright so i've been creating this web app that will enable users to save note(note taking app) i'm using express mongoDB for the backend and i've been looking for a way to ref the user that created the note(so that eventually every user can check only his own notes) anyways i looked arround and i didn't find any way to access the jwt payload 
here's my code : 
**notes.js**

```
exports.createNote = (req, res, next) =>{
    let note = new Note(req.body);
    note.user = req.user;note.save((err) =>{
    if(err){
        res.status(401);
        return next(err)
    }
    return res.status(201).json('note created successfully!')
})
```

};

**noteSchema.js**

```
let noteSchema = Schema({
    title : {type : String, require : true},
    description : {type : String, require : true},
    User : {type : String, ref : "User", require : true}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', noteSchema);
```

**authentication middleware**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) =>{
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    const userId= decoded.user._id
    try{
        if(req.body.userId && req.body.userId !== userId){
            throw 'invalid user ID';}}else{ 
            next();  
    }

}catch{
    res.status(401).json({ error : 'not authenticated !'});
}
```

i want to know is there any way to access the JWT Payload inside the note.js file (to extract the user._id)

Answer (score 0):

You could add to the `req` payload in your **authentication middleware**.

```js
module.exports = (req, res, next) =>{
    const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
    const userId= decoded.user._id
    try{
        if(req.body.userId && req.body.userId !== userId){
            throw 'invalid user ID';}}else{
            req.jwtPayload = decoded // add payload here to req
            next();  
    }

}catch{
    res.status(401).json({ error : 'not authenticated !'});
}
```

Then you could access it in **notes.js** like

```js
exports.createNote = (req, res, next) =>{
    const { jwtPayload } = req
    // do stuff with jwtPayload
    let note = new Note(req.body);
    note.user = req.user;note.save((err) =>{ // by the way, this will not behave as you expect
    // because it is an asynchronous callback 
    if(err){
        res.status(401);
        return next(err)
    }
    return res.status(201).json('note created successfully!')
})
```

Ensure your authentication middleware is **before** notes.js